# Breaking the 5000 object limit in Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I am using both FQML and Graph API to get all the photos URL of an album in Facebook.

Problem is, there are more than 5000 photos on that album and somehow both FQML and Graph API will just return photos 1 - 5000. I tried playing with the `limit`, `since` and `until` parameter but still no go.

Question: Is there a way to get past the 5000 object limit in Facebook?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this still the case? Did you find a work-around? I'm working on an FQL query to return friends of friends. I'm testing with my own UID and I have 540 friends now, which means >12,000 connections, of which >6500 are unique. I know this because the original code I wrote manually sifts through my friend list and queries each of them and then removes duplicates. Of course it took almost 3 minutes to run that every time, while the FQL query returns in 5 seconds. After an hour of searching for this answer I've come to the conclusion the only way to get around this is to write a mixture of the two

Comment: Yeah, I believe so. You can "watch" the bug filed on Facebook's bug tracker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook mutual friends and FQL 4999/5000 record limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281210/facebook-mutual-friends-and-fql-4999-5000-record-limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not currently.

Comment: What was this answer based? Link to source? Link to limitation? Is the answer still relevant?

Comment: @Cripto I was downloading data with Insights API on Ad level with country and region breakdown. Some days had 5000 rows as a result. Checked that days on FB Business Manager and it should be more than 5000. So answer seems to be still relevant as of May 2018.