# facebook graph api limit parameter

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am writing an application that needs to retrieve all posts on any given facebook page. For the McDonald's page, I would use this url:

https://graph.facebook.com/McDonalds/posts?access_token=xxx&limit=5000

The problem is that first, I do not receive any posts older than 2011-11-01 and the number of posts shown is much less than 5000. This means that the limit parameter isn't working properly. I looked this up and found that it was a known bug.

Then I tried to follow the next and previous paging information provided in the end and even using that I can't get past 2011-01-24. After following the next link 2 times, an empty page comes up. The McDonalds page is much older and contains more posts. So the question is, how on earth am I supposed to retrieve older posts. Is there any workaround at all?

Comment: There is a limit on the limit.  Try using since & until to extend the date params

https://graph.facebook.com/McDonalds/posts?access_token=xxx&limit=5000&since=2+years+ago&until=now

&limit=5000&since=2+years+ago&until=now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook mutual friends and FQL 4999/5000 record limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281210/facebook-mutual-friends-and-fql-4999-5000-record-limit)

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the limit.  Try using since & until to extend the date params

https://graph.facebook.com/McDonalds/posts?access_token=xxx&limit=5000&since=2+years+ago&until=now

```
&limit=5000&since=2+years+ago&until=now
&limit=5000&since=3+years+ago&until=now
```

Comment: same response. oldest post being 2011-11-01